# Change color of Floating Action Button from Appcompat 22.2.0 programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I would like to know how to change the Floating Action Button color from the Support library 22.2.0 ?
I've tried

```
button.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

but clearly, this changes the drawable of the button and it turns to a square.

Now I wonder how to change the color but just the color, without touching the shape?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31179286/2835520)

Answer (score 41):

Maybe late but could help.

```
 fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color
                    .parseColor("#33691E")));
```

and parse the actual color code from a list of colors [You can find here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)

Comment: Just to add to this: If you don't want to use a hardcoded string color value, and instead reference a color stored in your colors.xml, you can use the following:

`fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white)));`

Answer (score 32):

Create a `ColorStateList` and set it as the background tint:

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{0}}, new int[]{color}));
```

Comment: The colors will be set dynamically, so no xml resource files are possible

Comment: Then create the color state list dynamically?

Comment: Based on the question, the assumption is that `button` is a [android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html). This means that it would be restricted to v7.

Comment: Or simply ```ColorStateList.valueOf(color)```, from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32031019/1773325

Comment: A note: if setting the background color programmatically don't set any background color related properties in XML. Just found out the hard way that XML defaults will always override any runtimes changes from code (weird).

Answer (score 13):

To do this backwards compatible:

```
DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(fab.getDrawable()), tintColor); // <- icon
DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(fab.getBackground()), backgroundTintColor); // <- background
```

Answer (score 11):

Create a color resource in `colors.xml` (`R.color.purple` in this case) and use it like so:

```
floatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.purple));
```

Comment: Please consider explanatory text to accompany your code, to aid future readers.

Answer (score 11):

you have to use

- in XML with `attribute app:backgroundTint`
- in code with .setBackgroundTintList
  read this answer

[Android changing Floating Action Button color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color)

Comment: Thanks. its help me.

Answer (score 9):

**Method 1: Change floating action bar(fab) color in xml:**

To change floating action bar(fab) color just follow this step

just add "app:backgroundTint="#colorcode" " in xml of floating action bar(fab) ..  For example

```
app:backgroundTint="#8393ca"
```

at the place of #8393ca add any color code you want

Example as usaage..

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="#8393ca"
    android:src="@drawable/send" />
```

**Method 2: Change floating action bar color programmatically**

just add this line on your code

Firstly create a color red in your values=>colors then add this code in your activity on create

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.red));

                                or

fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#33691E")));
```

credits : http://androidrace.com/2016/12/12/how-to-change-fabfloating-action-bar-color-android/

Comment: This change also the text color to the same background color. How to avoid it or change the text color like #FFF?

Comment: And i noticed about if you are using an a drawable icon, this remove you that too.

Answer (score 6):

Check the accepted answer here: [Android changing Floating Action Button color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color)

> If you wish to change the color
>
> - in XML with attribute **app:backgroundTint**
> - in code with **.setBackgroundTintList**

Comment: This is only from API level 21.

Comment: @marienke Are you sure you used the `app` namespace in xml when testing below API 21?

Comment: @LouisCAD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108455/android-fab-setbackgroundtintlist-with-colorstatelist-not-working you asked for it :)

Comment: @marienke You just want to use a `ColorStateList` in your xml, use `setEnabled(isNfcEnabled)` from code to make it use the right color from your `ColorStateList` xml file.

Comment: @LouisCAD yes, that would be a correct way to do it, however, then I can't  listen for the user tapping the NFC FAB to tell them to go to Settings and enable the NFC on the device. I need to only change the colour of the FAB and based on the isNfcEnabled bool, determine where to go from a tap.

Comment: @marienke Then, look at `CheckedTextView` source code to make your FAB subclass have the `checked` state you'll use in your `ColorStateList`. You'll then just have to programmatically change the checked state of your FAB when NFC is switched on or off, probably using a `setChecked(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It will add a tint to the background resource.

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.yourColor));
```

Answer (score 1):

the attribute name is `backgroundTint`

so I thinks there's a function named

`button.setBackgroundTint(color)`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Floating action button library from https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton then use this

```
fab.setColorNormal(getResources().getColor(R.color.fab_color1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML background:tint color will always override whatever color you gave
programmatically. So to give color programmatically, remove `android:backgroundTint="#96989A"` line from the XML file and use:

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.yourColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you got your color in color file and you want to use that one.

**WHAT YOU CAN DO IS THIS CODE BELOW**

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.youcolor))));
```

As you know to change it programmatically, you need to use `setBackgroundTintList()`, then pass the `ColorStateList.valueOf()` which is required and this one take a certein int and parse it...

**Note: if you just put the int color right away it could give you problems to get the color you want sometimes and for that reason i don't use it and don't recommend it to use it like that**

Then put within `ColorStateList.valueOf()`, `Color.parseColor()` this is what you need to put...

This needs a String but **you have the int color in the color file, so what to do?**

Within `Color.parseColor()` pass `getString()`, this is a method that each activity has, so within `getString()` you put **finally** your color as this `R.color.yourcolor`

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin** this way:

```
binding.fAB.iconTint= ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"))
```

Where `binding` is a root view and `iconTint` comes from **Extended FAB**.

Answer (score -1):

just use this line in your xml file under floating action button

```
android:backgroundTint="#96989A"
```

Comment: That is not "programmatically"