# Setting drawable to floating action button ImageView in android

Tags: android

```
ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
icon.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.alarm);
```

When I want to set drawable icon it gives me error that android graphics drawable can not apply to `ImageView` ?

Comment: What's kind of "this"? "this" should be context here. Check "alarm" drawable is exists. Also give the full logcat to easy to investigate.

Comment: ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
        icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this , R.drawable.alarm));
        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(icon)
                .build();
        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);

Comment: tthis is code and still my icon is not apperaing on the floatingaction button .why?

Comment: I can't see the error in your code. Please try this `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alarm)`. And I think you were trying to use this [libs](https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateAndroid/blob/master/UltimateAndroidNormal/DemoOfUI/src/com/marshalchen/common/demoofui/circularfloatingactionmenu/MenuWithFABActivity.java), so learn tutorial about it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing ID of your resource in

```
icon.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.alarm);
```

method but this method takes only `Drawable` as parameter.
You should change your above call to this

```
icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.alarm));
```

Or you should call this method instead.

```
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm);
```

Comment: i have put icon which is in png format in drawable.. now i want to set this icon which i named is alarm ...now i want to set that alarm icon to my floating action button and it is returning me same android graphics error ?

Comment: Check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color

Answer (score 0):

Use `setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm)` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addPostBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mainBottomNavBar"
    app:maxImageSize="45dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/White"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_icon"
    app:useCompatPadding="true" />
```

Use the srcCompat keyword.