# How to add white background to a float action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button, action-button

I have a float action button which i implemented  on my MainActivity, am still a rookie and what i intend to achieve is to add a white background to this float action button when the button is clicked. This is the code am currently using, i will appreciate an edit to my code when answering:-

```
 final ImageView fabIconNew = new ImageView(this);
      fabIconNew.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_new));
    final FloatingActionButton rightLowerButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(fabIconNew)
            .build();


    SubActionButton.Builder rLSubBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
    ImageView rlIcon1 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView rlIcon2 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView rlIcon3 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView rlIcon4 = new ImageView(this);
    //ImageView rlIcon6 = new ImageView(this);


    rlIcon1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_contact));
    rlIcon2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_currency_info));
    rlIcon3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_exhibition));
    rlIcon4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_faq));
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32031019/5280641

Answer (score 1):

FAB's use the colorAccent attribute to get their colour. Change this in your theme to whatever colour you want it to be.

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Or change the background colour at run time like so:

```
rightLowerButton.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: am achieving this float button in java, and the white background is suppose to appear when the button is clicked

Comment: am getting an error which says: cannot resolve method getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Color in Java using:

```
rightLowerButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.your_color));
```

Comment: am getting an error on this line which says: should pass resolved colour instead of resource id here .getResources().getColor(R.color.white)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the color like this:

Java:

```
rightLowerButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorname);
```

XML (`layout/colors.xml`):

```
<xml>
   <color name="colorname">#FFFFFF</color>
</xml>
```

Comment: am getting an error which says: should pass resolved colour instead of resource id here .getResources().getColor(R.color.white)