# Change the floating action button background by a drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, floating-action-button

I would like to replace the circle of the floating action button by a drawable, I'm using this fab [fab on github](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/README.md)  I'm using this fab cause it work with SDK 14

It's the xml file :

```
      <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
            android:id="@+id/multiple_actions_saisiev2"
            android:layout_width="179dp"
            android:layout_height="368dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/dull_yellow"
            fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/dull_yellow"
            fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#182740"

            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_contre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/vert_fab"
                fab:fab_title="@string/contre"
                fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#FFFFFF"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/vert_fab"/>

            <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_perte"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/vert_fab"
                fab:fab_title="@string/perte"
                fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="#FFFFFF"
                fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/vert_fab"/>

        </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

If I use android:background it's not working, and If I change the background in the JAVA, the png appears on the background of the button.
I try to modifiy the library but nothing appears when I try to modify some thing.

Thanks

Comment: You should check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color

Comment: Thanks but this is only for change the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should help... the native use of Floating Action Button to set drawable attribute to it is like this.

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
```

[image: native fab icon]

or
from the library you are using, check the [implementation](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)

```
fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_star"
```

> Output
>   [image]

Comment: Thank for you answer but the fab:fab_icon not work nothing appears, and I try the first one but I try to add my png in the folder where the @android:drawable/ go to but he can't find my png

Comment: @VaudeyBaptiste, they have specific size make sure you do have those sizes, 64*64 for xhdpi, 48*48 for hdpi, 32*32 mdpi and 24*24 for ldpi

Comment: ok thanks and I don't know if I put the img in the good folder I go to : AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res  and I got a lot of drawable folder I need to put the img in every folder ?

Comment: you don't have to put images for android-plaform they can be accessed directly like this, "@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email", but when you want some of custom images you would have to put those size images in your project with respective drawable directory

Comment: yes but I would like to use a picture that I have create

Comment: in that case you need to make different size for that image as i mentioned and need to put them in respective directories