# Can not change FloatingActionButton's background color with background and backgroundTint in support design 23.2.0

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

This is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/enter_floating_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:background="#00FF00"
        app:backgroundTint="#00FF00"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/red"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
```

As you can see, I set `app:background` and `app:backgroundTint`, but these are useless, `FloatingActionButton's` background color doesn't change, and either the `app:rippleColor`, when i press the button it's color isn't which I set, looks like the accentColor in the theme.

Why don't these attributes work?

How can I change the `FloatingActionButton's` background and ripple color?

I had seen this: [Android changing Floating Action Button color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color). Some answers may work in 22, but I didn't find a useful way in 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating action button will be taking the color from colorAccent attribute in styles.xml.Set the color in a style and set that style for this Floating Action Button then it will work

Comment: This maybe useful but android:colorAccent requires API level 21, my API level is 14.

Comment: try to use like this   <item name="colorAccent">some color</item> without using the android namespace in the style which you are using.

Comment: I had tried this, not work. Maybe it's useful in design 22, i use 23.

Comment: @Swifter can you place the code of the style which you are using in styles.xml

Comment: I think I made a mistake, I should use android:theme="@style/***" not style="@style/***", and this solved my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add programmatically ripple color in your FloatingActionButton class:

```
        public RippleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
                mContext = context;
                init();
                TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                        R.styleable.RippleView);
                mRippleColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RippleView_rippleColor,
                        mRippleColor);
                mAlphaFactor = a.getFloat(R.styleable.RippleView_alphaFactor,
                        mAlphaFactor);
                mHover = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RippleView_hover, mHover);
                a.recycle();
            }


    public void init() {
            mDensity = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setAlpha(20);
          setRippleColor(Color.BLACK, 0.2f);
          // setRippleColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greycolor), 0.2f);
           // setRippleColor(0x000000, 0.1f);
        }

        public void setRippleColor(int rippleColor, float alphaFactor) {
            mRippleColor = rippleColor;
            mAlphaFactor = alphaFactor;
        }

 public void setHover(boolean enabled) {
        mHover = enabled;
    }
```