# floating action button with background tint cause error

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have tried to implement floating action button in my other project with fab and customize it and it works fine. But this time, when I create the fab object in my xml layout, it shows error. Feeling confused, it tried to remove some of it's tag and found out that giving the android:backgroundTint tag is when the error shows up.

Here is the code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_fab"
    android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"/>
```

Here is my build:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "2.0.4"
}
```

I have also added the google design gradle.

The error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxx/com.xxxx.xxxx.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #141: Binary XML file line #141: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

As soon as i remove the android:backgroundtint tag, the error is gone. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of  `android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"`, 
try with  `app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"`

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog), by default it takes the color set in **styles.xml** attribute **colorAccent**.

If you wish to change the color, in XML with attribute **`app:backgroundTint`**
 and not `android:backgroundTint`

So the final XML for fab icon will be

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:fabSize="mini"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_fab"
app:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
android:layout_margin="12dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answers given above, it is correct to add **`app:backgroundTint`** instead of **`android:backgroundTint.`** You can find the detail to this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color/31179286#31179286)

**Example :** `app:backgroundTint="@color/orange"`

I don't really know if I should delete this post since it might be kind of a duplicate, but I really appreciate your help guys.