# Background xml drawable doesn't cover the whole FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I created a red circle with xml, `red_circle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/Red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I use the above red circle as the background image of my `FloatingActionButton` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/red_circle"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

The result is this:

[image]

How can I have the red circle cover the whole FloatingActionButton?

Comment: Try this :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color)

Answer (score 0):

Change you accent color to Red because your `FloatingActionButton` theme will be `AppTheme`.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
```

Or you also change the color by programmatically

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorRed)));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a drawable or color list in java.
In your layout xml file, setbackground of FAB by
`app:backgroundTint="@color/yourColourRed"`
Reply me back if it really helps you.