# How to change floating action button color?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android, material-components

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(PrivateDealActivity.this, R.color.colorWhite)));
```

This is not working. How to change background color of floating action button

Comment: Please mark your code as code, and explain what you expect to happen as well as what actually happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android changing Floating Action Button color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color)

Comment: Using xml : app:backgroundTint="YOUR_COLOR_CODE"

Using programatically : floatingButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor("YOUR_COLOR_CODE")));

Comment: Please make sure you are using android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Comment: floatingButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor("YOUR_COLOR_CODE")));       //this code is not working for me.

Answer (score 7):

Using the **material components** [`FloatingActionButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md) and a [**material** theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) by default it uses the color with the attribute **`colorSecondary`**.

To change this color you have different options:

- You can use the **`app:backgroundTint`** attribute in xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       ...
       app:backgroundTint=".." />
```

- You can use a custom style using the **`<item name="backgroundTint">`** attribute

```xml
  <!--<item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton</item> -->
  <style name="MyFloatingActionButton" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">....</item>
  </style>
```

- starting from version **1.1.0** of material components you can also use the new **`materialThemeOverlay`** attribute to override the default color `colorSecondary` only for a component:

```xml
  <style name="MyFloatingActionButton" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyFabOverlay</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyFabOverlay">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/custom2</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: It works good but it changes other button properties as text style for example (all caps and letter spacing for sure, certainly others). Have you got a solution ?

Comment: @SebastienRieu why should it change other properties? You are extending the current style using parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"

Comment: You're right. It's because my button is an ExtendedFloatingActionButton so I had to apply the corresponding style. @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to change the background color:

```
FloatingActionButton button = findViewById(R.id.your_button);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && button instanceof AppCompatButton) {
    ((AppCompatButton) button).setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(*your color in integer*));
} else {
    ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, ColorStateList.valueOf(*your color in integer*));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this.

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this attribute:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is completely correct. I also wrote in a similar way for changing background color of floating action button ***programatically***. Just check your xml code once.
My XML Code :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"/>
```

Remember here, keeping `borderWidth="0dp"` is important.
Now, in Java Code :

```
fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(required_color));
```

Here you can replace **required_color** using `Color.parseColor()` or `ContextCompat.getColor()`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem would be to change your default colorAccent.

As stated in [Android Developers-FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton) :

> The background color of this view defaults to the your theme's colorAccent. If you wish to change this at runtime then you can do so via setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList).

If it is not possible to change your color accent, regarding the requirements of your project, but you need to implement this programmatically you can post your code and I'll be more than happy to update my answer.

Comment: the OP is using `setBackgroundTintList` and it's not working... so this answer doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
```

like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_student_house"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_house_add"/>
```

just note it is **app:backgroundTint** not **android:backgroundTint**

Also you could do it by adding style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.FloatingActionButton" >
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And give this style as theme in floating action button like below:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FloatingActionButton"

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_student_house"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FloatingActionButton"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_house_add"/>
```