# Floating button Background Color

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I have a problem with changing the FAB background color, it seems that the FAB have another background behind it

here my code

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_vote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

I would like to remove the purple/pink color behind it. right now the only solution that works is changing the colorAccent on my app, but it will affect other UI element

Comment: remove background tint from your floatingbutton

Comment: Or use this `android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: `android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"` set it `null` or `transparent`

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31179286/1318946

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code:
i have add this line in FloatingActionButton

```
app:backgroundTint="#000"
```

to change FloatingActionButton background

**Code**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="#000"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

I hope it Work for you

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below `android:backgroundTint="@color/pink"`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```