# Not working any solution to change a fab color programmatically

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I have to change fab color on click from blue to orange. I tried by myself but it wasn't working so i searched for an answer here on stack and came across some solution they were proposing but didn't work for me.

One of the question's i've came across was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969455/android-changing-floating-action-button-color):

so i've tried using:

`fab.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));`

`fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#33691E"));`

`mFab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources.getColor(R.color.mColor)));`

```
    private void onClickStart(View v) {
        int colorArancione = getResources().getColor(R.color.Arancione);

        if(mStatoScanButton) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mScanButton.setColorFilter(colorArancione);
                mScanButton.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add));
                //mScanButton.setForegroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.Arancione)));
                mStatoScanButton=false;

            startTimedScan();
        }else if(!mStatoScanButton){
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mScanButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue)));
            mStatoScanButton=true;
            if(bluetoothDevicesScansionati.size() == 0)
                mTestoTextView = "Nessun dispositivo trovato";
            fragment_dispositiviScansionati.updateTexto();

            try {
                mTio.stopScan();

            } catch (InvalidObjectException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/scanButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClickStart"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lustria"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:maxImageSize="35dp"
            app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            />
```

Comment: Why are these methods not working for you? Any errors?

Comment: No, it doesn't give me any errors it compiles fine, ah and i also obviously added the dipendencies

Comment: Can you paste your code here so that we could help you

Comment: ok i edited the post with my code

Comment: attach debugger, and check if it will even come to the line of the code where you change the color

Comment: yes, i've checked and it enters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your xml file you should use the property app:backgroundTint="@color/Blue" instead of android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue" like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/scanButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClickStart"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lustria"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:maxImageSize="35dp"
            app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            />
```

And Then you can use this method:

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(#33691E)));
```

Because this method don't work with the property "android:"

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was stuck on it for a whole day. Things like these make Android development suck :/

Answer (score 0):

The document suggests that it takes the @color/accent by default. But we can override it on code by using

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList)
```

but remember,

The minimum API version to use this library is 15 so you need to update it! if you don't want to do it

Comment: I'm trying with a a API 28 so it should be fine, I'm trying now