# Android FAB setBackgroundTintList with ColorStateList not working

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to change the colour of the NFC scanning FAB when NFC is not enabled. I've managed to successfully change the colour when the app launches, but if the user taps the FAB and enables NFC, the colour isn't changed to the primary colour. The logs say it does, but the change doesn't happen.

My `minSdkVersion = 15`

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/fab_scan_nfc"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
     app:borderWidth="0dp"
     app:elevation="6dp"
     app:fabSize="mini"
     app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
     app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     app:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAccent"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_nfc_n" />
```

Kotlin:

```
if (!isNFCEnabled) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Change NFC fab colour to disabled.")
    fab_scan_nfc.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.colorDisabled)
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Change NFC fab colour to primary.")
    fab_scan_nfc.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.colorPrimary)
}
```

This is the same as Java:

```
if (!isNFCEnabled) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Change NFC fab colour to disabled.")
    fab_scan_nfc.setBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.colorDisabled);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Change NFC fab colour to primary.")
    fab_scan_nfc.setBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.colorPrimary);
}
```

As a sideline - when the code does apply the disabled colour background tint, there is this smaller circle on the FAB which looks like a touch indicator. Does this have something to do with using a colour state *list* ?

[image]

Comment: That "touch indicator" is a small compat shadow. Something is definitely wrong here.

Comment: `ColorStateList.valueOf()` takes an actual color value for the argument. An `R.color` is a resource ID for a color in your app's resources, not a color value. Use `ContextCompat.getColor()` to get the actual value.

Comment: I don't see you using ColorStateList properly (put multiple colors each for a different state in one CSL). Instead you just manually assign different color after manually observing enabled state. You can define a CSL in XML.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not using the colour states correctly. I should have a separate XML file defining states and associated colours, and then programmatically do setEnabled(isNfcEnabled) when I check it. BUT, then I can't show a dialog when the user taps the NFC FAB to scan an NFC tag, to help them to the NFC settings.